# How to update TextView from a class that doesn't extend Activity class

Tags: android

I am New to Android. I am having a tough time with my code. 
Here is my problem. 
I have a TextView in my MainActivity which extends activity. And this textview has top be updated from another class which extends an Adapter class and implements GestureDetector.

Based on the fling event I am updating my textview. How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem atlast. I added the below line in the method present in my other class. So now when the method is called, my textView changes its text automatically.

```
mymainActivity.textView_name.setText((new myCurrentclass_Name(this.context_name)).some_array[value]);
```

This is how I was allowed to change the text of my TextView which I had in my MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Create a field in your Adapter class and assign the instance of your text view, or using MainActivity.this.findViewById(...) or just findViewById(...)  if your Adapter class is an inner non-static class of your MainActivity.

```
protected void onCreate(...) {
...
//I suppose you get your textView like this way
TextView textView = ((TextView) findViewById(...));
//I suppose your MainActivity extends from ListActivity
getListView().setAdapter(new YourAdapter(textView));
}

private static class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private TextView textView;
private YourAdapter(TextView textView) {
    this.textView = textView;
}
...
//somewhere
    this.textView.setText(".....");
}
```

or

```
// Inner non-static class
private class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
...
//somewhere
    ((TextView) findViewById(...)).setText("...");
}
```

Comment: Can I just have a simple code snippet of this. I couldn't get it.

Comment: Wrote some snippets for you :)

Comment: Simply Easy way !!..Works Perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `TextView static` or you can take a field in your `AdapterClass` and pass that `TextView` to the Constructor of `AdapterClass` while you have finished all in `AdapterClass` your can update the `TextView` from `AdapterClass`

**Edit:**

say it is your AdapterClass:

```
public class AdapterClass extend BaseAdater..(blah blah)
{
    TextView textView;
    public AdapterClass(Context context, TextView view)
    {
                this.context = context;
                this.textView = view;
    }
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        //do your task


        textView.setText("123 Results found");
    }
}
```

and in your Activity while declaring AdapterClass
pass your textView to the constructor like:

```
AdapterClass adapter = new AdapterClass(this, textView);
```

Comment: Can you please explain it with a simple code. I couldn't get you.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But will this code work if my class extends a Abstract class instead of some adapter. What happens in that case.

Comment: Well BaseAdapter is an Abstract class, So definitely this will work.