# How to set a TextView from another class (not extending to Activity.class)

Tags: android

I have a problem about setting a TextView from a class which is not a child class of Activity. This class is basically used for handling registration and REST request with 3rd party server.

After getting textfield info from 3rd Party server, it is too late to set TextView in the Main Activity.

- I can't use SharedPreferences to set this info, because MainActivity has already started.
- I can't pass this info with Bundle since my java class is not an activity class.

How can I pass this info and set the TextView in the MainActivity? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It's hard to provide a solution without seeing the actual implementation.

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813785/how-to-update-textview-from-a-class-that-doesnt-extend-activity-class

Comment: try to use textView as static and using yourMainActivity.textview.setText("test");

Comment: When you call the method in this particular class, does it return any data?

Comment: One approach is to send broadcast when data is ready in your method  and on you have to create a class which extends receiver and tou have to over write onReceive() and on that method you can create Intent and pass that string as Intent to Activity and on Activity you can set data in TextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way of doing this this is to create a listener.

Create an interface :

```
public interface OperationCompletedListener{
void onOperationCompleted(String resultValue);
}
```

Then in your class which calls Rest services, create a variable for this listener and a method to set it.

```
private OperationCompletedListener mListener;

public void setOperationCompletedListener(OperationCompletedListener listener){
mListener=listener;
}
```

Then when the your rest service completed call like below :

```
if(mListener!=null){
mListener.onOperationCompleted("your value to be passed");
}
```

Then in your activity class which contains the TextView, create an object of OperationCompletedListener and set it to the other class using the set method that we created earlier. Then in the onOperationCompleted method, set the text view with your value and you are done.

```
private OperationCompletedListener mOperationCompletedListener=new OperationCompletedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onOperationCompleted(String resultValue) {
        yourTextView.setText(resultValue);
    }
};

restServiceClassObject.setOperationCompletedListener(mOperationCompletedListener);
```

Comment: I can't realize where I should use restServiceClassObject.setOperationCompletedListener(mOperationCompletedListener); call. Can you please help?

Comment: That should be in your activity class which contains the text view.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an static method which update textview in your activity class . Then call this method from your other class whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the `Activity` to the non-`Activity class` when you instantiate it. For example:

```
public class NonActivityClass {
    private Activity parentActivity;
    public NonActivity(Activity parentActivity) {
        this.parentActivity = parentActivity;
    }
}
```

Or you can just pass the `Activity` to a static method in your `NonActivityClass` if you don't want to instantiate it (it's `abstract`). Then, you can inflate the `TextView` or do a `findViewById` from the parent and set the text.

From my experience, you should never use a static **non-final** variable to maintain a reference across activities. When you restart the app or the phone, or when Android kills your app's process, the reference and state of the variable becomes lost and may cause your app to crash.